# How to add a password to the "Use password for:" list

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, passwords, autofill

I have multiple Google accounts. When I am going to login to Google I am presented with a list of users. I select the user that I want to login with, then I click in the password field, there is the dropdown list with "Use password for:" options. However, one of the users is not listed in the list, how do I add the password to the list?

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on the Chrome flag chrome://flags/#PasswordForceSaving then you get a key icon in the address bar whenever a form is visible. Clicking this will force the 'save password' bubble to pop up, allowing you to add an extra user/password to your saved list.

Comment: They've changed this URL to chrome://flags/#PasswordForceSaving

Comment: `PasswordForceSaving` doesn't seem to exist anymore

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that in your browser setting the two labels are enabled:

- Enable Auto-fill to fill in web forms in a single click.
- Offer to passwords with Google Smart Lock for Passwords.

then log in again to your google account, it will ask if you want to save the password, choose yes.

Now you will see it.

You can refer to this link

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Since there is a list of passwords and that Chrome remembers passwords for new sites I will assume that Auto-fill is enabled.

Comment: Offer to save passwords and auto-fill are enabled.

Comment: hope this [link]https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en will help you

Comment: I have a special situation. I removed the account from the list, re-added it and Chrome still did not prompt to save the password. I disabled and enabled Offer to save passwords and that also did not work.